# Overriding admin template does not work

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I checked similar questions but I couldn't make the solutions work.
I'm following the official [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial02/)

I added the following to ./mysite/settings.py:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
```

and I edited the `h1` tag in `./templates/admin/base_site.html` to this:

```
{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name"><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">Foo Administration</a></h1>
{% endblock %}
```

And here is the folder structure :

```
.
├── manage.py
├── mydb.sqlite3
├── mysite
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.py~
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── wsgi.pyc
├── polls
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── admin.py~
│   ├── admin.pyc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.py~
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
└── templates
    └── admin
        ├── base_site.html
        └── base_site.html~
```

I restarted everything (including the computer :) ) still no luck, the heading is always 'Django Administration'. Where am I doing wrong?

Also, here is the shell output for :

```
>>> from mysite import settings
>>> settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS
['/home/me/DjangoProjects/mysite/templates']
```

Thanks for any help!